# Creating iOS app preview in iMovie but getting iTunes Connect Error

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, imovie

I'm creating an app preview for an iOS app using [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/imovie/Creating-App-Previews-with-iMovie.pdf) (record video using QuickTime, import into iMovie, File -> App Preview) yet I get the following error message when I attempt to upload the video:

"Your app video preview is in the wrong format. For more information, see the Developer Guide".

The video is Mpeg 4, 640x1136 etc. so this seems odd. Has anyone been able to upload a video in this way?

[image: iTunes Connect error]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: I recreated the videos using the latest version of OS X and iMovie and that seemed to fix it (I had the error when I was using the beta versions).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick using just iMovie and Quicktime to get the right dimensions.

1. Use QuickTime to record a short clip from the size of the device you need
2. Use iMovie and insert that clip into a new "App Preview" project
3. Add your actual video after the short clip

Now, any clips that you export will be in the right dimensions.

If you need to hide your short clip, you can shorten it to 0.1 seconds. Put a title over it and delete the text. Now your video starts with 0.1 seconds of a black screen.